# Reactjs render same route after page refresh of browser

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am new on reactjs and stuck in a scenario. It has two pages: public and protected. User can see protected page only when he was signed in. when user login the application with credentials it lands on the dashboard page(protected page) from their if user navigate to some other page like User List(protected page) from dashboard and here if user try to refresh the page it takes user back to dashboard page instead to stay on the current page i.e User List page.

Below is the Route Page of my code:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/forgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
          <PrivateRoutes exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          <PrivateRoutes exact path="/userlist" component={UserList} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And Private route code is:

```
class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    let componentData = '';
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
       componentData = <div><SideNavigation /> <Route render={() => <this.props.component {...this.props} />} /> </div>;
    } else {
       componentData = <Redirect to="/login" />;
    }
    return componentData;
  }
}
```

Above code takes user back to the dashboard(protected page) page from UserList page instead to load the same page.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is send to `PrivateRoute` the prop `isAuthenticated`? Looks like the component `PrivateRoute` requires this prop, but it isn't send at any time.

Comment: Hi @macabeus thankks for reply, this.props.isAuthenticated comes from the redux

Comment: can you provide the code of `UserList` component?

Answer (score 0):

Do the code refactor like this

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
          <PrivateRoutes path="/userlist" component={UserList} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/forgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
          <PrivateRoutes path="/" component={Dashboard} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Assuming your private route works fine.